# Link in PHP not displaying

Tags: php, hyperlink

I am creating a panel that allows users to go back to previous pages. However, I am having difficulties with the second link.

```
<a href='discussions.php'><?php echo $category_section; ?></a>
                <?php $back_topics; ?>
                <a></a>

$back_topics ="<a href='forum_view_category.php?cid='".$cid."'>Back to Topics</a>";
```

Nothing shows up in that link box. What am I doing wrong with it?

UPDATE

```
$stmt->bind_result($topic_id, $category_id, $topic_title, $topic_creator, $topic_last_user, $topic_date, $topic_reply_date, $topic_views); 

    if (!$stmt) {
        throw new Exception($con->error);
    }
}
$stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows;

if($numrows == 1){
?>
        <div class="page_background">
            <div class="page">
                             <div class="forum_links_out">
                    <a href='discussions.php'>Discussions</a>
                    <a href='discussions.php'><?php echo $category_section; ?></a>
                    <?php
                    $back_topics ="<a href='forum_view_category.php?cid=$cid'>".$topic_title."</a>";
                     echo $back_topics; ?>
                    <a></a>
                </div>

<?php

        if ( $_SESSION['user'] ) { 
            echo "<input type='submit' class='repy_view_topic_button' value='Reply to Thread' onclick=\"window.location = 
        'forum_post_reply.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid."'\">";
        } else {
            echo "<p>Please log in to add your reply</p>";
        }
?>      
        <table class="forum_view_topic_table">
<?php
        }

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        //added in topic title variable
?>
        <div class="view_topic_thread_name_out">
            <div class="view_topic_thread_name">Thread: <?php echo $topic_title;?></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: you forget `echo ` `<?php $back_topics; ?>`

Comment: make sure you place your variable before you echo it too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the HTML you're generating:

```
$back_topics ="<a href='forum_view_category.php?cid='".$cid."'>Back to Topics</a>";
                       ^--start href value          ^--end href value
```

which means your `$cid` value is an unknown/invalid attribute itself:

```
<a href='forum_view_category.php?cid=' 42'>
                                       ^^^---illegal/unknown attribute
```

You want

```
$back_topics ="<a href='forum_view_category.php?cid=$cid'>Back to Topics</a>";
                                                   ^^^^^
```

instead.

Comment: Why wouldn't this echo out `$topic_title` when I echo the `$back_topics` variable? I have it like this `$back_topics ="<a href='forum_view_category.php?cid=$cid'>".$topic_title."</a>";
      echo $back_topics; ?>`

Comment: `var_dump($topic_title)` and see what's in there.

Comment: It is coming up NULL and I think I know why. I was trying to get `$topic_title` from my bind_result of my query, but I have the variable `$topic_title' over my fetch and while loop, but I'm not sure how I can do this because I can't move the fetch/while loop or else it may affect the rest of my page. I am updated my question to show the page.

Comment: Would I have to do a separate query just to get that?

Answer (score 0):

original

```
<a href='discussions.php'><?php echo $category_section; ?></a>
<?php $back_topics; ?>
            <a></a>
 $back_topics ="<a href='forum_view_category.php?cid='".$cid."'>Back to Topics</a>";
```

change to

```
$back_topics ="<a href='forum_view_category.php?cid='".$cid."'>Back to Topics</a>";
<a href='discussions.php'><?php echo $category_section; ?></a>
<?php echo $back_topics; ?>
```